# Adapt query to return correct results

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the bellow query. Here i  collect all rows and skills, Unwind rows as row and check that candidates skills are in all skills i want, i check that every skill related to this candidate is on the list of ALL skills i want.
I need to change somehow the query because i want the query return me Candidates only if "Knows" all required skills AND for every skill has the same or more years of experience.
In a nutshell, if a Candidate Knows all skills and for every skill has same or more years of experience, i want this node, otherwise no.
Any ideas?

```
WITH  [
        {entity_id: 7, years_of_experience: 5},
        {entity_id: 23776, years_of_experience: 1 },
        {entity_id: 17477, years_of_experience: 1 }
      ]  AS rows
UNWIND rows AS row
MATCH  (s:SkillNode)
  WHERE s.entity_id = row.entity_id
WITH  collect(row) as rows, collect(s) as allSkills, s
UNWIND rows as row
MATCH (c:CandidateNode)-[r:KNOWS]->(s)
  WHERE  (r.years_of_experience>=row.years_of_experience AND s in allSkills)
WITH c, collect(distinct r) as rels, collect(distinct s) as skills, allSkills
  WHERE ALL(sk in allSkills where sk in skills)
RETURN skills, rels, c;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is not the exact query that you want because I am using skill name rather than entity_id BUT it can be similar to what you want.

Steps:

> 1. Put required skills and years of experience in one list (rows)
> 2. Search each required skills in SkillNode to ensure it is valid
> 3. Filter out candidates based on years of experience per Skill
> 4. Pick out candidates that have ALL skills in required skills (rows)

```
WITH  [
        {name: "Java", years_of_experience: 5},
        {name: "Spring Boot", years_of_experience: 1 } 
      ]  AS rows
UNWIND rows AS row
MATCH  (skill:SkillNode) WHERE skill.name = row.name
WITH  rows, row
// Validate the skills
MATCH (c:CandidateNode)-[r:KNOWS]->(s:SkillNode) 
    WHERE s.name  = row.name 
// Check if the years of experience is good
WITH c, r, s, rows, row 
    WHERE r.years_of_experience >= row.years_of_experience
// Check that candidate has ALL skills required 
WITH c, rows, collect(s) as candidateSkills 
    WHERE ALL(skill in rows WHERE skill.name in [c in candidateSkills|c.name]) 
RETURN c

Result:
╒════════════════╕
│"Candidate"     │
╞════════════════╡
│{"name":"Leo"}  │
├────────────────┤
│{"name":"Manos"}│
└────────────────┘
```

Sample graph:
[image]

Comment: You are always Top! Many thanks for your answer!

Could i ask something more?
in ```WHERE ALL(skill in rows WHERE skill.name in [c in candidateSkills|c.name]) ```
what is exactly this "[c in candidateSkills|c.name]" ?

Comment: That's formally known as a list comprehension, but basically this is just a way to transform elements of a list. For each element in the list, we want the element's name instead, so we end up with a list of names rather than nodes. List comprehensions can also do filtering, if we added a WHERE clause in there.